# Debugging in VS2017 and Missing Method Exception

Tags: visual-studio-2017

1. The project is a C # project with managed C ++ libraries.

   Setting: x64 debug

   Problem: When debugging, C ++ routines are not jumped in, even if there a

   ```
               Breakpoint is set !!!

               The C ++ dll and pdb files are up to date!
   ```
2. If a new routine is built into this C ++ library for test purposes,

   there is a "Missing Method Exception" when this routine (method) is called at runtime

   However, this new method is displayed in the object catalog!
3. The project is ported from VS2010. It worked there
4. It works in x86.
5. The project settings are the same in x64 and x68.